# Retrieve data with 3 tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to reach a field in a table and I do not know how to do it. I have a table where I have all the data (TespEolReference), another intermediate table I have the EolMedia table where it mentions the table TespTaxon and the field taxonRecordId, which is the field that I am interested in updating . I am developing it to create a new record. Update the ones in the database if you leave me but entering a new one does not show it in the form. I leave my code for you to see.

Thank you!!

**TespEolReferenceData.java**

```
 * TespEolReference generated by hbm2java
 */
public class TespEolReferenceData  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private String idreference;
     private TespTPublicationtype tespTPublicationtype;
     private String fullReference;
     private Set<TespEolmedia> tespEolmedias = new HashSet(0);
     private BigDecimal idtaxon;
     private String scientificname;
}
```

**TespEolReference.java**

```
public class TespEolReference extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idreference;
    private TespTPublicationtype tespTPublicationtype;
    private String fullReference;
    private Set tespEolmedias = new HashSet(0);
}
```

**TespEolMedia.java**

```
public class TespEolmedia extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal idmedia;
private TespTAudience tespTAudience;
private TespTType tespTType;
private Set tespTaxons = new HashSet(0);
private Set tespEolReferences = new HashSet(0);
}
```

**TespTaxon.java**

```
public class TespTaxon extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal taxonid;
    private TespTAmbitos tespTAmbitos;
    private BigDecimal taxonrecordid;
    private BigDecimal idtaxonomicstatus;
    private String source;
    private String tmpDatasetid;

    private Set<TespEolmedia> tespEolmedias = new HashSet<TespEolmedia>(0);
    private Set<TespEolReference> testEolReference = new HashSet<TespEolReference>(0);
}
```

**ApplicationServiceUtils.java**

```
public static TespEolReference getTespEolReference(
            TespEolReferenceData tespEolReferenceData) {

        try {

            TespEolReference tespEolReference = new TespEolReference();

            if(tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference() != null && !tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference().equals("")) {
                tespEolReference.setIdreference(new Long(tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference()));
            }

            tespEolReference.setFullReference(tespEolReferenceData.getFullReference());


            **if(tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon() != null && !tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon().equals("")) {
            //  TespEolmedia tespEolmedia = new TespEolmedia();

                TespTaxon tespTaxon = new TespTaxon();
                tespTaxon.setTaxonrecordid(new BigDecimal(tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon()));

                HashSet tespTaxons = new HashSet();
                tespTaxons.add(tespTaxon);
                tespEolReference.setTespEolmedias(tespTaxons);
            }**

            return tespEolReference;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ha ocurrido un error en getTespEolReference: " 
                    + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static TespEolReferenceData getTespEolReferenceData(
            TespEolReference tespEolReference) {

        try {

            TespEolReferenceData tespEolReferenceData = new TespEolReferenceData();

            tespEolReferenceData.setIdreference(tespEolReference.getIdreference().toString());

            tespEolReferenceData.setFullReference(tespEolReference.getFullReference());



            return  tespEolReferenceData ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ha ocurrido un error en getTespEolReferenceData: " 
                    + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**TespEolReference.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolReference" table="TESP_EOL_REFERENCE" schema="DBA_IEPNB">
        <id name="idreference" type="long">
            <column name="IDREFERENCE" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_TESP_EOL_REFERENCE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="tespTPublicationtype" class="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTPublicationtype" fetch="select">
            <column name="IDPUBLICATIONTYPE" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="fullReference" type="string">
            <column name="FULL_REFERENCE" />
        </property>
        <property name="primarytitle" type="string">
            <column name="PRIMARYTITLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="TITLE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TespEolMedia.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolmedia" table="TESP_EOLMEDIA" schema="DBA_IEPNB">
        <id name="idmedia" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="tespTaxons" table="TESP_TAXON_EOL_MEDIA" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTaxon">
                <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="tespEolReferences" table="TESP_EOLMEDIAEOLREFERENCE" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolReference">
                <column name="IDREFERENCE" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TespTaxon.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26-ago-2016 9:41:02 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTaxon" table="TESP_TAXON" schema="DBA_IEPNB" lazy="true" >
        <id name="taxonid" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="tespPliniancoreExtension" class="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespPliniancoreExtension" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="TAXONRECORDID" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </many-to-one>

        <set name="tespEolmedias" table="TESP_TAXON_EOL_MEDIA" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolmedia">
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Did you debug your application? And can you post some minimal code or better a [mcve]? All those unnecessary attributes and log statements make the code a pain to read.

Comment: Oh, the mapping would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Thomas hibernate?

Comment: @Thomas the problem is in ApplicationServiceUtils, I need to get to taxonRecordId from TespTaxon table through TespEolMedia. I have not got it, I'm still a newbie: :(

Comment: Do you mean to get the id from the object created in this line: `TespTaxon tespTaxon = new TespTaxon();`? If yes then note that Hibernate doesn't know you've created that object so nothing can be loaded and nothing will be automatically saved.

Comment: it has been a test without foundations, should the object tespEolMedia?

Comment: "test without foundations" - you mean without any prior knowledge? If that's the case you'd better grab some tutorial and follow thow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163698/discussion-between-bufank85-and-thomas).